# How to make WebStorm not auto-close the tabs of temorarily removed files

Tags: intellij-idea, tabs, phpstorm, webstorm, auto-close

Let's say I create a new branch then create `newFile.js`, then commit and switch back to the previous branch. This makes WebStorm auto-close the tab of `newFile.js`. This is very irritating when often switching between branches and making small fixes.

How can I fine-tune this behavior?

Comment: AFAIK (99.99%) it's not possible (no such GUI setting available): the architecture of IDE does not allow to work with "hang up in the air" files (i.e. that do not exist any more). This behaviour goes in line with auto-save feature. But yes -- some sort of notification (at least) about such action would be good to have.

Comment: I'm afraid you're right. Thanks!